# Keep rows of a 2d array where the value of a specified column exists in a flat whitelist array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, array-intersect

I need to get intersection of 2 arrays that have different dimensions, but I don't know if it's possible with `array_intersect()`.

I tried to do :

```
$result = array_intersect ($ONE, $TWO)
```

but it does not work.

$ONE:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => monday-1
            [title] => monday-1
            [id] => 2878
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => tuesday-1
            [title] => tuesday-1
            [id] => 3180
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => friday-1
            [title] => friday-1
            [id] => 3181
        )

)
```

And $TWO:

```
    Array
(
    [1] => monday-1
    [2] => tuesday-1
    
)
```

so I need to get

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => monday-1
            [title] => monday-1
            [id] => 2878
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => tuesday-1
            [title] => tuesday-1
            [id] => 3180
        )
)
```

Comment: Please, provide more details about code

Comment: well there is no more code, i jus try to setup array_intersect function in PHP to get my result...

Comment: i also tried with loops : 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($two); $i++)
{
 
 for ($j = 0; $j <count($one) ; $j++){
     if ($one[$j]['name'] == $two[$i])
    {
        echo  $one[$i]['name'];
         
    }
}
}

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask good question with correct tags. From your question I cannot understand that it is PHP

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a solution :

```
 for ($i = 1; $i <= count($two); $i++)
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($one) ; $j++){
          if ($two[$i] == $one[$j]['name']  )
        {
           $result[$j]['name']=$one[$j]['name'];
           $result[$j]['title']=$one[$j]['title'];
           $result[$j]['id']=$one[$j]['id'];

        }
    }
    }
```